# Django: Many-to-many through a table with (only) compound key

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

I have a legacy database with a table storing a many-to-many relationship, but without a single primary key column. Is there any way to convince Django to use it anyway?

Schematically:

```
Product 1<---->* Labeling *<---->1 Label
```

The `Labeling` table uses `(product_id,label_id)` as a compound primary key, and I don't see any way to inform Django about this. (Just using `through` gives me `Unknown column 'labeling.id' in 'field list'`.)

Do I need to fall back to custom SQL? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a `unique_together` to the model for the many-to-many table, Django will use those columns instead of expecting a primary key called `id`.

Comment: Not really, it will create `id` field as well. There's a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28712960/52499). But actually in my case I decided to go with extra `id` field. No legacy tables.

Answer (score 2):

hope this helps you,

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.db_index

Comment: I didn't expect it would... but it did: `unique_together` is all that is needed to stop Django asking for a primary key column. If you add that (or words to that effect) to your answer I can accept it. (Afaik `db_index` is irrelevant: it applies only to individual fields.)

Comment: While it is true that Django doesn't complain anymore if you add unique_together *but* it is still not fully functional. For example delete (Model.Delete()) on the model in specified in the through parameters will except. I'm expert enough to dare gives this as an answer, for what I read Django doesn't support no having a primary key on a Model.

Comment: @Tikitu Thank you, thank you, thank you! I was tearing my hair out trying to figure a way to make Django not require a `primary_key=True` column for my legacy read-only database with several many-to-many intermediate tables. I knew about `unique_together`, but I didn't realize it would make Django's insistence upon `primary_key=True` go away. Now that Django 1.8 actually issues warnings about setting `primary_key=True` on a ForeignKey field, this suddenly became very important.