# Composite primary key in django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a legacy db table which has composite primary key. I don't think I will be able to change the structure to include a surrogate key, as there is some code written that uses that table. And in django, I cannot use that table, as it doesn't have a primary key(non-composite).

Do django models support composite primary keys? If not, is there any workaround without changing the structure of the table?

P.S. I am using postgresql.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Try similar below code:

```
class MyTable(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('key1', 'key2'),)

    key1 = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    key2 = models.IntegerField()
```

or if you want only unique mixed fields:

```
class MyTable(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('key1', 'key2'),)

    key1 = models.IntegerField()
    key2 = models.IntegerField()
```

EDIT: I would like to note that there is a problem with this approach if there are 3 columns. Update queries don't work because it tries to update (puts pk fields right after "SET") the fields that are unique together and obviously fails.

Comment: in Meta class every tuple in `unique_together` attribute determining that mixed values of these fields by determined ordering must not duplicate.

Comment: I mean, when you create `key2 = models.IntegerField(unique=True)`, shouldn't it imply that `key2` must be unique for all values not just for a single `key1`?

Comment: Ok, for my case, the first one worked but I can't really understand why. The second version still needs a primary key.

Comment: `unique_together` related `key2` value to `key1` value.

Comment: Same here.  The first code snippet worked.  (Also working with a legacy db)

Comment: There was a suggested edit saying the following:  I would like to note that there is a problem with this approach if there are 3 columns. Update queries don't work because it tries to update (puts pk fields right after "SET") the fields that are unique together and obviously fails.

Comment: Thing to be noted here is that the first solution is a workaround to make Django not to create `id` field. It creates `PRIMARY KEY` index only for `key1`. Not to both.

Comment: Just curious if this has been fixed?  Because I tried to duplicate the issue by using an update query like the following, on data model named `Quote`, but it works without error: `Quote.objects.filter(exchange=exchange).update(time_units='1m')`.  Is mine the correct way to perform an `Update query`?

Comment: Just a note that the first suggestion is *not* equivalent to having a composite primary key because setting `primary_key = True` on `key1` makes it unique, which means that you won't be able to add a new combination of `(key1, key2)` if the value of `key1` already exists in the table. A composite primary key is about unique _combinations_ of fields. The second suggestion kind of works, but it does not prevent Django from creating an 'id' column automatically. By the way, this is a [*15-year-old problem*](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/373)!

Comment: @M.javid, may I know if this works at database level or in application itself? As I'm concerned in under LB, multiple app would be consistent?

Comment: Why is this marked as the accepted answer? I am pretty sure Django will spit out an error about key1 not being unique.

Answer (score 41):

The accepted answer is fine. However, it's a little old. `unique_together` may be deprecated in favor of [UniqueConstraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint). So, the better way of doing this would be;

```
UniqueConstraint(fields = ['key1', 'key2'], name = 'constraint_name')
```

Comment: The accepted answer mentions that you can only use a max of 2 fields for the composite key with their code - does this change with yours?

Answer (score 18):

I [solved](https://viewflow.medium.com/the-django-compositeforeignkey-field-get-access-to-a-legacy-database-without-altering-db-tables-74abc9868026) this with virtual field inherited from django AutoField, that combines a values from several fields into single JSON dict.

That makes such models, compatible with django admin and genetic views.

`$ pip install django-viewflow --pre`

```py
from viewflow.fields import CompositeKey

class Seat(models.Model):
    id = CompositeKey(columns=['aircraft_code', 'seat_no'])
    aircraft_code = models.ForeignKey(
        Aircraft, models.DO_NOTHING,
        db_column='aircraft_code'
    )
    seat_no = models.CharField(max_length=4)
```

This makes possible to access as to [legacy databases](https://github.com/viewflow/cookbook/tree/v2/legacy_db), as to [PostgreSQL TimeScaleDB](https://github.com/viewflow/cookbook/tree/v2/timescale_db) tables

Comment: Is it possible to have other models with Seat as a foreign field with this method?

Answer (score 9):

Another option is to set `managed=False` in the model's `Meta`, then manually create the table.

```
class MyTable(models.Model):
    foo = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    bar = models.IntegerField()
    baz = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'myapp_mytable'

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<MyTable: MyTable object ({self.foo}, {self.bar}, {self.baz)>'
```

In a postgres shell:

```
CREATE TABLE myapp_mytable (
    foo INTEGER NOT NULL,
    bar INTEGER NOT NULL,
    baz INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(foo, bar, baz)
);
```

It appears to behave correctly:

```
>>> MyTable.objects.create(foo=1, bar=1, baz=1)
<MyTable: MyTable object (1, 1, 1)>

>>> MyTable.objects.create(foo=1, bar=1, baz=2)
<MyTable: MyTable object (1, 1, 2)>

>>> MyTable.objects.create(foo=1, bar=1, baz=2)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "myapp_mytable_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (foo, bar, baz)=(1, 1, 2) already exists.
```

**Note** that this is only tested in Django 3.x, so I'm not sure if it works in older versions.