# How to create an associative entity with extra fields in django

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

I am facing the following problem.

I have to entities,***Proposal*** and ***User***, a user can vote up or down several proposals and a proposal can have several votes from several users.

This relation between Proposal and User is Many to Many, the thing is that here I want to add an extra field to indicate if the Vote is positive or negative.

Is there are a way to do this in Django using ManyToManyField?, or the only way to do this is creating the model entity of Vote by hand like this:

```py
    class Vote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='voter',null=False)
    proposal = models.ForeignKey(Proposal,related_name='vote_to',null=False)
    opinion = models.BooleanField(blank=False,null=False)
```

And in case I have to do it by hand, how I can do for saying to Django that the primary key is the composition of the others Foreign keys

Comment: Associating `User` directly with the `Proposal` does not very well indicates the precise logic of Vote. It is best to create a separate model `Vote`.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a separate model Vote is a better way to do it, because a vote is specific to a particular proposal for a particular user, so it can't be directly linked to the Proposal model or to the User model.

See this [article](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/MultipleColumnPrimaryKeys) regarding mutiple column primary keys support in Django, and also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712848/composite-primary-key-in-django/28712960#28712960).