# Django. Create composite primary key

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I want create composite promary key like {id, project_id}. I remove old tables(all). when i do:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

I have a mistake:

```
AssertionError: Model mdm.Group can't have more than one AutoField.
```

change my model:

```
id = models.AutoField(db_index=True, primary_key=False)
```

and add composite primary key as

```
constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(
            fields=['id', 'project_id'], name='unique_group_project'
        )
    ]
```

From docs:

```
By default, Django gives each model the following field:

id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

This is an auto-incrementing primary key.

If you’d like to specify a custom primary key, just specify primary_key=True on one of your fields. If Django sees you’ve explicitly set Field.primary_key, it won’t add the automatic id column.

Each model requires exactly one field to have primary_key=True (either explicitly declared or automatically added).
```

I just don't understand the problem. If I add AutoField, It's necessarily must PK. How I can resolve problem with Autofield id and composite PK (id, project_id)?

Comment: From what I remember Django doesn't support composite PKs.  If there is a hack to get around it, I think you'll run into issues if you try to use Django's other built-in functionality.  This may be useful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712848/composite-primary-key-in-django

Comment: Thank you. I saw this topic.  Problem is AutoField must been PK. I want set id in AutoField and don't stand PK.